# Updating label positions in a for loop

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, label, pine-script

```
    if barstate.isconfirmed and bar_counter == add_databy
        for e = 0 to par - 1
            if run_model == true and matrix_.get(0, 0) == feature_matrix_train.get(0, 0)
                train_label.set_xy(x=index_array.get(e), y=price_array.get(e))
                train_label.set_xloc(x=index_array.get(e), xloc=xloc.bar_index)
                train_label.set_yloc(yloc=yloc.price)
                train_label.set_text(text=str.tostring(pred_class.get(e)))
                train_label.set_textcolor(color.white)
                train_label.set_color(color=pred_class.get(e) == 0 ? color.red : pred_class.get(e) == 1 ? color.yellow : pred_class.get(e) == 2 ? color.green : na)
                train_label.set_style(style=label.style_label_center)
                train_label.set_size(size=size.normal)
            if run_model == true and matrix_.get(0, 0) == feature_matrix_test.get(0, 0)
                test_label.set_xy(x=index_array.get(e), y=price_array.get(e))  
                test_label.set_xloc(x=index_array.get(e), xloc=xloc.bar_index)
                test_label.set_yloc(yloc=yloc.price)
                test_label.set_text(text=str.tostring(pred_class.get(e)))
                test_label.set_textcolor(color.white)
                test_label.set_color(color=pred_class.get(e) == 0 ? color.red : pred_class.get(e) == 1 ? color.yellow : pred_class.get(e) == 2 ? color.green : na)
                test_label.set_style(style=label.style_label_center)
                test_label.set_size(size=size.normal)
```

The code above exists in a function which is called twice within my algorithm. The first time its called with a training matrix and the second time with a testing matrix. When its called the first time with the training matrix I want it to plot the signals from the training data in the correct position of the training set, then when called again with testing data plot the signals in the correct positions in the testing set. I tried using label.new and label.delete but I ran into issues getting the labels to delete, now im trying label.set and its not printing off any labels. Here is the code below could someone please tell me where my error exists, thanks!